# files.forEach(function(file) { ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

```
var testFolder = '/zip_file\ /sit1_Wave2_Settlement_afx_formula\ \
(1\)/data_dictionary/CM.173/';
   var fs = require('fs');
      fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);

});
})
```

I need to read a file contents, if i execute the above code it shows an error.

```
files.forEach(function(file) {
   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Comment: `fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => { if (err) return console.log(err); ...`

Comment: means  there is no any content in `files`..

Comment: It shows same error only.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for errors before trying to read the files, and then check to see if the files object is defined, like this:

```
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (files){
        files.forEach(file => {
            console.log(file);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('no files found')
    }
});
```

Comment: if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/project/'
    at Error (native)
It throws an error..

Comment: In my case it was not able to fetch correct directory and hence the files were undefined. Try to give the correct path and get more details by logging the error.